# Теряются пакеты.

Tags: windows

Пингую до майл.ру. Теряются пакеты. Проблема может быть в модеме? (если да, то как ее можно устранить?)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала в командной строке Windows выполните:

```
tracert www.mail.ru
```

и предоставьте отчёт программы

p.s. на всякий случай: откройте окно командной строки, нажав кнопку Пуск и выбрав пункты Все программы, Стандартные и Командная строка.

Answer (score 1):

[Mail.ru](http://Mail.ru) достаточно удаленный адрес, для начала не плохо бы пропинговать собственный шлюз или DNS провайдера.Данную информацию можно посмотреть в командной строке ipconfig /all.Вывод сюда, если возникнут сложности в понимании.